# Confusing word order of "more a lowering of some positions..."

Tags: word-order, complements

Consider:

> “It was a risk-off shift in the last three days,” Benno Galliker, a
>   trader at Luzerner Kantonalbank AG in Lucerne, Switzerland, said.
>   “It’s probably **more a lowering of some positions into the summer**. The
>   Fed minutes could be very important. There are some rumors about some
>   hawkish comments.”
>   ....
>   British insurers **led a gauge** of European insurance companies **lower**
>   after a report showed U.K. prices for new-car insurance fell for a
>   record 10th quarter.
>
> -- [Source](http://www.garp.org/risk-news-and-resources/risk-headlines/story.aspx?newsId=114053) *Europe Stocks Little Changed Before Fed as Espirito Santo Falls*

I cannot fully grasp the meaning of the first bolded sentence.

Since **lowering** is a gerund here, why is it that "*It’s probably **more a lowering** of some [financial] positions into the summer*",

not "*It’s probably **more of** a lowering of some positions into the summer*",

or "*It’s probably a **more** lowering of some positions into the summer*",

or "*It’s probably **more than** a lowering of some positions into the summer*"?

Besides, does **gauge** metaphorically refer to a certain index for the European insurance industry here? Is **lower** here an adjective, acting as an object complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since lowering is a gerund here, why is it that "It’s probably *more a lowering* of some [financial] positions into the summer", not "It’s probably *more of a lowering* of some positions into the summer" or "It’s probably *a more lowering of* some positions into the summer" or "It’s probably *more than a lowering* of some positions into the summer"?

All four of these constructions have distinct meanings.

- *a more lowering of* - this is ungrammatical. It means that the positions had already been lowered previously and have now been lowered again. The correct phrase replaces *more* with *further*.
- *more than a lowering* - this means that what happened was something bigger, more important, or more significant than a (mere) lowering. It's very likely, though not guaranteed, that lowering was part of what happened, but it definitely wasn't all of it.
- *more of a lowering* - this is used to state that the previous description was incorrect, and the item at hand is more like a lowering than whatever was said before. The two things are on a continuum, and the action should be placed closer to *lowering*.
- *more a lowering* - this is very close to *more of a lowering*, but there's much less equivocation. It's appropriate to call it a lowering, and not whatever was said before. The hedging from *more* is usually done for the sake of politeness; saying "well, I think it's really this" as opposed to outright stating that something is wrong.

You can parse Galliker's remarks this way:

> "Some people have said the reasons for this are [something]. I'm not going to say that they're wrong, but I think the real cause is shifting off risk by reducing positions."

He's expressing it politely, but the bulk of his message is that he significantly disagrees with whatever the other analysts said.

> As for the second one, does gauge metaphorically refer to a certain index for the European insurance industry here? Is lower here an adjective, acting as an object complement?

There's no metaphor here. *Gauge* is used as in [Collins definition 7](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gauge?showCookiePolicy=true): an assessment, test, or measurement. In this specific case the article is financially technical, so you can read *gauge* as *rating*, *outlook*, *assessment* or *guidance*. *Gauge* is definitely not an index or set of companies; it's referring to a single prediction about the collective performance of a specific industrial sector. It's not clear from the excerpt who issued the assessment, but presumably it's more or less common knowledge to those who find it relevant.

*Lower* is acting as an adverb modifying *led*. The use of *led* tells us that British insurers saw the greatest reduction of expectations, but most if not all European insurers and the sector as a whole had their predicted profits/revenues/etc lowered. *Led* is used in the sense of *leading a group*; in this case, the group is European insurers and they are being led towards worse performance.

You can read it like this:

> British insurers had the largest reduction in predictions of financial performance among European insurance companies, who all saw some lowering of expectations, after a report showed U.K. prices for new-car insurance fell for a record 10th quarter.

Comment: Good answer. But I doubt **lower** can act as an adverb. At least, the dictionaries don't count it as one. I think the sentence pattern is similar to "He painted the wall blue", in which case **blue** grammatically funtions in the same way as **lower**.

Comment: In general English, it's not. But in finance jargon, *lower* can be used this way, often with *guide*. E.g.: [1](http://www.investopedia.com/stock-analysis/2013/riptides-at-riverbed-technology-rvbd-ffiv-csco0213.aspx) [2](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2014-03-19/fedex-misses-across-board-guides-lower-cuts-capex-spending-forecast-blames-it-all-we) [3](http://www.zacks.com/stock/news/131140/Q1-Is-Devoid-Of-Growth-And-Outlook-For-Upcoming-Quarters-Is-Cloudy) [4](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/earnings-beat-agco-shares-fall-142003944.html). *The company guided lower* is standard and complete.

Comment: +1! Thx. So what does "guide" and "lead" mean in the field of finance?

Comment: *Guide* means to issue guidance; i.e. make a statement about expected performance during the upcoming or current period (usually quarter or year). Most commonly this is used when senior management of companies supply guidance for their own firms, but also sometimes it's for independent analyst predictions. Here, *led* is not jargon; it's the usual sense of *leading a group*. British insurers led the lowering of European insurers; thus British companies had their guidance lowered by the greatest margin. Sorry, I read the passage wrong initially (it's *British insurers*, not *British analysts*).

Comment: In your deleted "insurance companies aren't actually in yet", what does 'in' mean? Obviously it doesn't mean 'fashionable'. And I would have thought 'lead' was always a positive word, as in 'the department led the world in cancer research.' But it's being negative here. kind of surprised me.

Comment: *In* there means *reported*, *received* or *published*; *the results aren't in* is a common phrase meaning *the outcome is still in question*. Try thinking of *led* in this case as meaning *pulling everyone in a certain direction* (like a tour guide) rather than *being first in the rankings*. The former is naturally neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Of your two questions I can only answer the first.

The first two versions "more a lowering" and "more of a lowering" have the same meaning. They both have the feeling of "more like a ______" and can be read that way.

The third version: "a more lowering" does not make sense.

The final version: "more than a lowering" changes the meaning. The phrase "more than" means that the action taken is greater than the action usually associated with a lowering, instead of the original meaning that the action taken was close to the strength of a lowering than any other comparison.

[image: comparison of "more than" vs. "more of"]

Answer (score -1):

1) Either is acceptable:

- It's more a burgandy than a red.
- It's more of a burgandy than a red.

So,

- It’s probably more a lowering of some positions into the summer.
- The risk-off shift is probably more of a lowering of some positions into the summer (than anything else).
- The risk-off shift is most likely due to some firms lowering some positions due to the summer (for some "summer" reason... perhaps lowering some cyclic positions that are more risky in the summer?)

Note that this can also be interpreted/translated as:

- Blah blah blah-blah blah, blah-blah blah blah blah.
  (Who cares what some analyst "thinks" about why some move occurred over three days... nobody really knows!)

2) Upon review of some examples, I think "a gauge of companies" is "a set of companies that represents ***something***".  As such, it can be as generic or specific as a writer wishes.

So "led a gauge of insurance companies" (I think...not 100% sure) means the author is thinking of some set of companies, like an index, and perhaps ***is*** an index, but the author doesn't think it's important enough (for any of a number of reasons, including space constraints) to provide more specifics.